# Can't Install php-mssql or freetds on Centos7

Tags: centos, php, sqlserver

My goal is to connect to MS SQL Server 2005 using PHP. I have installed PHP and ODBC. I am running CentOS7.

```
PHP Version => 5.4.16
```

.... (from php -i) ....

```
odbc

ODBC Support => enabled
```

I am running into 2 dependency issues when trying to install freetds and php-mssql extension. (see below)

```
[root@localhost freetds-dev.0.92.377]# yum install php-mssql freetds
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.supremebytes.com
 * epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: ftp.osuosl.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package freetds.x86_64 0:0.91-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) for package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit) for package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-mssql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-mssql-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have libgnutls.so version 28 though

```
/usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.28
/usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.28.20.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you are trying to install has `el6` in the version, indicating it is for CentOS 6, not 7. It appears you have added the EPEL repository for the wrong version CentOS. You should remove the `yum` configuration for EPEL6 and add the configuration for 7. You can add the configuration for 7 with the following:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.oss.ou.edu/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: I used `yum remove epel-release` then `rpm --rebuilddb` before your command.

Comment: I did the same, still no love.  `Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)`.  I'm using RHEL 7.2.

Comment: @acoder your error message still has el6 in it. It appears you did not properly remove the EPEL config for RHEL 6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same issue and I know I'm on OS 7.

Should I try to install freetds separately?

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

Installed:
  epel-release.noarch 0:7-9

Error: Package: freetds-0.91-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)

/usr/lib64/.libgnutls.so.28.41.16.hmac
/usr/lib64/.libgnutls.so.28.hmac
/usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.28
/usr/lib64/libgnutls.so.28.41.16
```